# Is silverlight platform independent?

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, web

Can I develop apps for WEB, Android, IOS, etc using Visual Studio and Silverlight.
If yes then what all do I require to configure my PC, so that I can develop apps for all platforms at one place.

OR

if silverlight can't be used then what all do i need to have on my PC, to develop apps for the above mentioned platforms.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Silverlight does not work well with Mac Chrome (as it is 32-bit). Silverlight cannot be viewed in iOS.

Comment: Xamarin works well with Android & iOS, but it isn't designed for web. PhoneGap is designed to use web technologies for mobile apps (WP, Android, iOS, BBOS, Bada).
Of course HTML5 also have the promise that 'one day' every web can be host app that run offline on any browser, but you probably can't afford to wait for it

Answer (score 0):

You can develop web apps .All web browsers in desktop chrome,ie ,firefox suport it.But in mobile only windows mobile supports it.Also mac doesnt support.If you are starting now i recommend to go with html5.
you can use mvc framework in .net 4.5
Install visual studio 2012,sql server 2012.Get started..

Comment: Odd, Windows Mobile is considered obsolete by now. What web apps that can run on WM but can't run on newer, more standard compliant browsers like IE in Windows Phone, Safari in iOS and Chrome in Android?

Answer (score 0):

A responsive HTML5 website framework (for example [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)) is what you need. For server-side coding, you can choose your favorite programming language (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, etc). Also, you have to consider which programming language your web server supports.

Definitely NOT Silverlight, or Flash, as they require to install an extra plugin to browsers. Mobile browsers do not support this.